# D3/JS mapping a JSON data callback

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have seen many examples with `d3.csv()` callback mappings such as:

```
var data = raw_data.map(function(d) { return 
    variable1 : +d.variable1,
    variable2 : +d.variable2
});
```

However I'm trying to figure out how to use `map.()` for a JSON callback. The reason being is I have a  attribute d: expected number, "MaNn", "NaNz" error. This error if I'm not mistaken, is often associated with data being parsed as a string. The JSON looks to be in numbers/floats, but just in case D3 is parsing my data as strings, I want to map it as numbers so I can rule out the parsed as a string culprit from my console log error. So, what I tried was roughly the same as the csv case above, using the unary `+`:

```
var json = raw_json.map(function(d)  { return
    xs: +d.xs,
    ys: +d.ys,
    id: +d.id
});
```

At this point, the error was still there. However I'm not sure if I fully rejected my null hypothesis of string parse error because I'm not totally confident that my JSON data `.map()` is of the right syntax. I'm kind of in limbo at the moment.

**Question:** Is my `.map()` totally wrong? Is there something more I can do to troubleshoot the expected number error?

I realize that JSON files have a wide range of data structures. Here is a screen shot of what my `console.log(raw_json)` looks like in the console log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map()` does not match your JSON data. Your JSON consists of *one array* having *one object* containing *three arrays* for `id`, `xs` and `ys`. To convert all those strings to numerical values you need three separate loops:

```
var obj = raw_json[0];
obj.id = obj.id.map(id => +id);
obj.xs = obj.xs.map(x => +x);
obj.ys = obj.ys.map(y => +y);
```

Or, preferably, since you do not need to create new arrays while only converting to numbers, you could also do the conversion on the spot using `.forEach()` instead of `.map()`.

```
const toNum = (d, i, a) => { a[i] = +d };   // Conversion function

var obj = raw_json[0];
obj.id.forEach(toNum);
obj.xs.forEach(toNum);
obj.ys.forEach(toNum);
```

Have a look at the following working example:

```js
var raw = `
  [{
    "id": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "xs": ["11", "12", "13"],
    "ys": ["21", "22", "23"]
  }]
`;
var data = JSON.parse(raw);

const toNum = (d, i, a) => { a[i] = +d };   // Conversion function

var obj = data[0];
obj.id.forEach(toNum);
obj.xs.forEach(toNum);
obj.ys.forEach(toNum);

console.dir(data);
```

Comment: Would I want to use `obj` or `raw_json` for a line generator? `.attr('d', lineGenerator(raw_json)`. I tried both, neither had any errors. Path expects an array right? So I could use `raw_json` and it will be numbers correct? I went with your `const` conversion approach.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Not directly related to your question, but since you asked for a line generator... You might also want to pass your arrays through [`d3.zip()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#zip) to get *one* array of individual point arrays: `d3.zip(obj.id, obj.xs, obj.ys)`. This will yield `[[1, 11, 21], [2, 12, 22], [3, 13, 23]]` which can be passed to the line generator and will help simplifying your accessor functions.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Expanding on my last comment, this could significantly be simplified by just doing `var data = obj.id.map((id, i) => [+id, +obj.xs[i], +obj.ys[i]]);` replacing both my above snippet as well as `d3.zip()` with just one line.

Comment: After a few hours of experimenting I couldn't get that last solution (or any of the other ones) to be recognized by my line generator. Although I agree with your assessment that the convert to number issue is resolved, now it's a separate matter. Your approach looks very promising, I'd really appreciate further advice on my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923223/d3-line-generator-handling-multiple-arrays). I provided more details and uploaded a block.